# Create rows in Oracle SQL - Complex

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table MEASURES

| M_ID | MBK_NAME | MCP_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | null | MCCP |
| 11 | MCCP | LOOPS |

I want to run a SQL to get the following output

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | MCCP |
| 11 | MCCP01 |
| 11 | LOOP |
| 11 | LOOP01 |

So 2 rows in the table need to become 4
Some indicated an inline view might help

In case you want to try :

```
CREATE TABLE MEASURES
("M_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
 "MBK_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
 "MCP_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE));

Insert into MEASURES (M_ID,MBK_NAME,MCP_NAME) values (10,null,'MCCP');
Insert into MEASURES (M_ID,MBK_NAME,MCP_NAME) values (11,'MCCP','LOOPS');
commit;
```

**UPDATED TO ADD LOGIC as Requested**
thanks @JR and @DR great. There are more cols in the table m_id, mbk_name and mcp_name are one with logic.

**Logic**

- Find distinct mbk_names / mcp_names where length >=4 chars
- For each - find the associated 2 latest records in MEASURES (by m_id)
- where there than 2 or more rec take first 2 based on m_id. Output should be that m_id
- where there is only 1 use same id for both and create ABCD and ABCD01 records

**Other permuatations for input are**

```
-1-
M_ID   MBK_NAME   MCP_NAME
51     JDKJPP     JDKJPP
57     JDKJPP     JDKJPP
61     JDKJPP     JDKJPP

OUT
51 JDKJ JDKJPP JDKJPP
57 JDKJ01 JDKJPP JDKJPP

-2-
M_ID MBK_NAME MCP_NAME
101 HTTPKHN_GT HTTPKHN_GT

OUT
101 HTTP HTTPKHN_GT HTTPKHN_GT
101 HTTP01 HTTPKHN_GT HTTPKHN_GT

-3-
M_ID MBK_NAME MCP_NAME
15 PIPSTT KOOLXX 25 PIPSTT KOOLXX

OUT
15 PIPS PIPSTT KOOLXX
25 PIPS01 PIPSTT KOOLXX
15 KOOL PIPSTT KOOLXX
25 KOOL01 PIPSTT KOOLXX
```

**Data for Above examples**

```
-- Test 1
TRUNCATE TABLE MEASURES;
Insert into MEASURES (M_ID,MBK_NAME,MCP_NAME) values 
(51,'JDKJPP','JDKJPP');
Insert into MEASURES (M_ID,MBK_NAME,MCP_NAME) values 
(57,'JDKJPP','JDKJPP');
Insert into MEASURES (M_ID,MBK_NAME,MCP_NAME) values 
(61,'JDKJPP','JDKJPP');
commit;

-- Test 2
TRUNCATE TABLE MEASURES;  
Insert into MEASURES (M_ID,MBK_NAME,MCP_NAME) values 
(101,'HTTPKHN_GT','HTTPKHN_GT');  
commit;

-- Test 3
TRUNCATE TABLE MEASURES;
Insert into MEASURES (M_ID,MBK_NAME,MCP_NAME) values 
(15,'PIPSTT','KOOLXX');
Insert into MEASURES (M_ID,MBK_NAME,MCP_NAME) values   
(25,'PIPSTT','KOOLXX');
commit;
```

Comment: select new_name, m_id, mbk_name, mcp_name from .... results r rows ->  MCCP, 10, null, MCCP  |  MCCP01 11, MCCP, LOOPS  | LOOP, 11, MCCP, LOOPS |  LOOP01, 11, MCCP, LOOPS

Comment: Which rules lead from source to target? Why the result contains only one row for M_ID = 10 and three rows for M_ID = 11? How and why did LOOPS become LOOP?

Comment: Please post your current attempt and describe what is the issue with this code. You may use `union` of the same queries with `'01'` appended to each `MCP_NAME`. But why did you show two columns (`MCP_NAME`, `MBK_NAME`) if the result doesn't contain any data from `MBK_NAME`? What is the logic behind the transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**
After your instructions here is the answer using MODEL claouse. But first the data - I collected all 3 of your tests data into table MEASURES adding a column TEST (A, B, C) so I could see all the differences. The data looks like this.

| TEST | M_ID | MBK_NAME | MCP_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 51 | JDKJPP | JDKJPP |
| A | 57 | JDKJPP | JDKJPP |
| A | 61 | JDKJPP | JDKJPP |
| B | 101 | HTTPKHN_GT | HTTPKHN_GT |
| C | 15 | PIPSTT | KOOLXX |
| C | 25 | PIPSTT | KOOLXX |

And here is the code based on SQL Modeling used in second CTE (a_model). The first one (grid) is just some data preparation.

```sql
WITH
    grid AS
        (
            Select
                TEST,
                M_ID,
                0 "IDX",
                0 "ITER",
                --
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TEST ORDER BY TEST, M_ID) "IDS",
                Count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY TEST ORDER BY TEST) "NUM_OF_ROWS",
                Sum(1) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY TEST, M_ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "RN",
                --
                MBK_NAME "MBK_NAME",
                SubStr(MBK_NAME, 1, 4) "MBK_4",
                --
                MCP_NAME "MCP_NAME",
                SubStr(MCP_NAME, 1, 4) "MCP_4",
                --
                CASE WHEN SubStr(MCP_NAME, 1, 4) = SubStr(MBK_NAME, 1, 4) THEN 'SAME' ELSE 'DIFF' END "COMPARE",
                SubStr(Nvl(MBK_NAME, MCP_NAME), 1, 4) "BASE_1",
                CASE 
                    WHEN CASE WHEN SubStr(MCP_NAME, 1, 4) = SubStr(MBK_NAME, 1, 4) THEN 'SAME' ELSE 'DIFF' END = 'SAME' THEN SubStr(MBK_NAME, 1, 4) 
                ELSE
                    SubStr(MCP_NAME, 1, 4) 
                END "BASE_2" 
            From
                MEASURES
            Where
                Length(MBK_NAME) >= 4 OR Length(MCP_NAME) >= 4
            Order By TEST, M_ID

        ),
    a_model AS
        (
            SELECT 
                Nvl(ITER, 1) "ITER", IDX,
                TEST, IDS, M_ID, RN, NUM_OF_ROWS, 
                BASE_1, BASE_2, MBK_NAME, MCP_NAME, COMPARE
                COMPARE
            FROM
                grid
        
            MODEL
                PARTITION BY (TEST)
                DIMENSION BY (IDS)
                MEASURES (ITER, IDX, M_ID,  RN, NUM_OF_ROWS, BASE_1, BASE_2, MBK_NAME, MCP_NAME, COMPARE) --, MAX_ID)
                RULES ITERATE(2)
                    (
                          M_ID[1 + 1] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'SAME'
                                                THEN CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN M_ID[1] ELSE M_ID[1 + 1] END
                                        ELSE CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN M_ID[1] WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 2 THEN M_ID[1 + 1] ELSE M_ID[CV()]  END
                                        END,
                          IDX[1 + 1] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'SAME'
                                              THEN CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN IDX[1] ELSE IDX[1 + 1] END
                                        ELSE CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN IDX[1] + 1 WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 2 THEN IDX[1 + 1] + 1 ELSE IDX[CV()]  END
                                        END,
                          NUM_OF_ROWS[1 + 1] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'SAME'
                                                    THEN CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] ELSE NUM_OF_ROWS[1 + 1] END
                                                ELSE CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 2 THEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1 + 1] ELSE NUM_OF_ROWS[CV()]  END
                                                END,
                          MBK_NAME[1 + 1] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'SAME'
                                                    THEN CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN MBK_NAME[1] ELSE MBK_NAME[1 + 1] END
                                               ELSE CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN MBK_NAME[1] WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 2 THEN MBK_NAME[1 + 1] ELSE MBK_NAME[CV()]  END
                                              END,
                          MCP_NAME[1 + 1] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'SAME'
                                                  THEN CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN MCP_NAME[1] ELSE MCP_NAME[1 + 1] END
                                            ELSE CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN MCP_NAME[1] WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 2 THEN MCP_NAME[1 + 1] ELSE MCP_NAME[CV()]  END
                                            END,
                          RN[1 + 1] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'SAME' 
                                            THEN CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN M_ID[1] ELSE RN[1+1] END
                                      ELSE CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN M_ID[1] WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 2 THEN RN[CV()] ELSE RN[CV()] END
                                      END,
                          BASE_1[1 + 1] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'SAME' 
                                                THEN CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN BASE_1[1] ELSE BASE_1[1 + 1] END
                                          ELSE CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN BASE_1[1] WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 2 THEN BASE_1[1 + 1] ELSE BASE_1[CV()]  END
                                          END,
                          BASE_2[1 + 1] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'SAME' 
                                                THEN CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN BASE_2[1] ELSE BASE_2[1 + 1] END
                                           ELSE CASE WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 1 THEN BASE_2[1] WHEN NUM_OF_ROWS[1] = 2 THEN BASE_2[1 + 1] ELSE BASE_2[CV()]  END
                                          END,
                          M_ID[1000] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'DIFF' THEN M_ID[1] ELSE 0 END,
                          BASE_1[1000] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'DIFF' THEN BASE_1[1] ELSE 'x' END,
                          BASE_2[1000] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'DIFF' THEN BASE_2[1] ELSE 'x' END,
                          MBK_NAME[1000] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'DIFF' THEN MBK_NAME[1] ELSE 'x' END,
                          MCP_NAME[1000] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'DIFF' THEN MCP_NAME[1] ELSE 'x' END,
                          M_ID[2000] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[2] = 'DIFF' THEN M_ID[2] ELSE 0 END,
                          BASE_1[2000] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'DIFF' THEN BASE_1[1] ELSE 'x' END,
                          BASE_2[2000] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'DIFF' THEN BASE_2[1] ELSE 'x' END,
                          MBK_NAME[2000] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'DIFF' THEN MBK_NAME[1] ELSE 'x' END,
                          MCP_NAME[2000] = CASE WHEN COMPARE[1] = 'DIFF' THEN MCP_NAME[1] ELSE 'x' END
                    )
        ORDER BY TEST, IDS, RN
        
        ),
    my_data AS
        (
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.ITER, a.IDX, a.TEST, a.IDS, a.M_ID, a.RN, a.NUM_OF_ROWS, 
    a.BASE_1, a.BASE_2, a.MBK_NAME, a.MCP_NAME, a.COMPARE
FROM
    a_model a
INNER JOIN 
    grid g ON(
                (g.TEST = a.TEST And g.IDS = a.IDS)
              OR
                (g.COMPARE = 'DIFF' And a.IDS IN(1000, 2000) And a.M_ID > 0)
              OR
                a.M_ID = a.RN
                
            )
WHERE (a.IDS <= 2 And a.IDX Is Not Null) OR a.IDS IN(1000, 2000)
ORDER BY 
    a.TEST, a.IDS, a.RN
      )
SELECT 
    M_ID, 
    CASE 
          WHEN IDS = 1 AND COMPARE = 'SAME' THEN BASE_1 WHEN IDS=  2 AND Nvl(COMPARE, 'SAME') = 'SAME' THEN BASE_2 || '01'
          WHEN IDS = 1000 THEN BASE_2 WHEN IDS = 2000 THEN BASE_2 || '01'
          WHEN IDS = 1 THEN BASE_1 WHEN IDS = 2 THEN BASE_1 || '01'
    END "NEW_NAME",
    MBK_NAME,
    MCP_NAME
FROM
    my_data
ORDER BY
    TEST,  
    IDS, M_ID
```

... the resulting dataset  is

| M_ID | NEW_NAME | MBK_NAME | MCP_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51 | JDKJ | JDKJPP | JDKJPP |
| 57 | JDKJ01 | JDKJPP | JDKJPP |
| 101 | HTTP | HTTPKHN_GT | HTTPKHN_GT |
| 101 | HTTP01 | HTTPKHN_GT | HTTPKHN_GT |
| 15 | PIPS | PIPSTT | KOOLXX |
| 25 | PIPS01 | PIPSTT | KOOLXX |
| 15 | KOOL | PIPSTT | KOOLXX |
| 25 | KOOL01 | PIPSTT | KOOLXX |

Modeling could be used to add rows and/or columns to the resulting dataset and to manipulate the data by addressing the individual cells of row-column grid just like in an excel sheet. Yes, it does look pretty complex and odd but it can be used to solve something as complex as your question.
I didn't have time to clean the code and there are some things left that I used while searching for solution that are not needed anymore.
Regards...
P.S. More about the Oracle's MODEL clause ( https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm ) and a small example ( http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11663.html )

Comment: Thanks @DR appreciate it - incorrect for Test 1, 2 and 3

Comment: @ttc Just posted the updated answer. Regards...

Comment: Hi DR, very impressive,  and for me very complex.  Would you mind while its in your head to write a few lines of explanation for myself and others who may want to use these constructs.  If you could explain use of MOEL, PARTITION and DIMENTION or give a link  as reference.  Again really appreciate your reponse and time taken

Comment: Sorry, it would take too much space to explain it but I posted a link to the page that I started with. The MODEL clause is very much like dealing with cells in excel sheet. There is also a link to one simple example how to use it. Thanks for accepting. Regards...

Answer (score 0):

MBK_NAME appears to be irrelevant.

Create a table with two rows, containing
the text `''` and `'01'`.

JOIN against that table.
The Cartesian cross product will give you the desired four rows.

---

You mentioned (11, MCCP01),
but I *think* you meant (10, MCCP01).